# Создать бд в Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, mvc, asp.net-core

Как я понял, у меня получается мультитенантное приложение на ASP.NET Core MVC. При регистрации нового пользователя, для него должна создаваться новая БД. Структура БД для всех пользователей одинаковая. Как это можно сделать? Использовать SQL запрос для создание БД, при регистрации или можно это сделать средствами EF?

Comment: Уже не первый раз встречается такой вопрос: хочу создавать БД для каждого пользоватея. Зачем??? На каждого пользователя не нужна не только БД, но даже таблица не нужна. Достаточно записи в таблице.

Comment: Пользователь это, можно сказать, новая организация в системе, которая включает в себя еще пользователей (сотрудников).  Смотрел сравнения между общей БД и отдельной БД для каждого. В общей базе меньше уровень изоляции.